# 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am facing an error while making connection through SignalR. When I make SignalR connection, just after connection starts, it instantly gets disconnected and throws an error.

> Error: Connection disconnected with error ‘Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.’.

```
public startConnection(): void {
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${this.API_URL}/interviewRoundHub`).withAutomaticReconnect([5000])
      .build();
    if (this.hubConnection && this.hubConnection.state === "Disconnected") {
      this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
        console.log('SignalR connection started.');
        this.getStatus()
        //this.candidateList?.unshift(this.candidateList[0]);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error('SignalR connection error:', error);
      });
    }
  }

  getStatus(){
      this.hubConnection?.on('FrontEndMethod', (assessmentStatus, candidateInviteId) => {
        console.log(assessmentStatus);
        console.log(candidateInviteId);
        this.message.assess = assessmentStatus;
        this.message.cand = candidateInviteId;
        this.receivedStatus.next(assessmentStatus);
        this.receivedCandidateId.next(candidateInviteId);
        this.message1.next(this.message)
      });
  }
```

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
var currentUserId = _currentUser.GetId();
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetByIdAsync(currentUserId);
var currentUserRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(currentUser);
if (!_connectionsMap.Any(u => u.Key == currentUserId))
{
_connectionsMap.Add(currentUserId, Context.ConnectionId);
}
if (currentUserRoles.Count > 0 && currentUserRoles.Any(x => x == _stringConstant.TeamAdmin))
{
_teamAdminMap.Add(currentUserId, Context.ConnectionId);
}
return base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
var userId = _currentUser.GetId();
_connectionsMap.Remove(userId);
if (_teamAdminMap.ContainsKey(userId))
{
_teamAdminMap.Remove(userId);
}
return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

[image]

I am expecting SignalRconnection.

Comment: Any updates about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We can find the logs fron the browser, it breaks inside `getStatus()`, so we need to check the FrontEndMethod function in backend.

We also can enable [server-side logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0#server-side-logging) to check more details.

Usually `InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.` means the model inside the `FrontEndMethod` has some issue.